# How can I get the UNDO-stack with PropertyChangeUndo objects from the MementoService in Catel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel, memento

I'm developing an application with undo/redo mechanism. I use the Catel MVVM framework. I use the Catel.Memento for the undo/redo. I got worked it, but I want to show the list of redo-objects in a list.

My question is: How can I get the redo-objects from the MementoService? I want to know the oldvalue, newvalue and propertyname of each object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the IMementoService.RedoBatches property, which can be found here:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/5234dcf4f66188ab1cc5c35089375a6bccb139fd/src/Catel.Extensions.Memento/Catel.Extensions.Memento.Shared/MementoService.cs#L155

I agree it's not really well documented on Confluence (official Catel project docs), but since you are working on a nice example, I think you can contribute some ;-)

Comment: I know, but have used this one. I did this in my code: _mementoService.RedoBatches.ElementAt(0).Actions.ElementAt(0); with this code I can't get the PropertyChangeUndo-object from the collection. I want the collection of _actions with PropertyChangeUndo-objects and his properties oldvalue, newvalue and description